# How do I use My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText in VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to write data to a file:

```
Public Sub test()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\username\Desktop\outlook.txt", "test", True)
End Sub
```

I get this error popup:

[image: image description]

There's an Add reference window. Do I need to add some library here?

[image: image description]

Comment: Remove the parentheses?  Office VBA can easily create files without needing to resort to calling .Net over COM

Comment: What parentheses? Do I call it as a command line command? And how do I properly separate arguments?